# How do I find the first digit after a decimal point?

Tags: python

I don't have any specific code that I'm using, I'm just curious about finding the first digit after decimal point using `int(input())`.

Comment: You can't. That code will throw an error even before the decimal point could be used for anything

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Are you trying to find if the string from input() is an int or float?

Answer (score 3):

With

```
x = float(input())
```

You can either use arithmetic operations. `x - int(x)` will give you only the digits after the decimal place. You can the multiply by 10 and cast to an integer

```
print(int((x - int(x))*10))
```

**Edit**

To handle negative numbers with the arithmetic method

```
print(abs(int((x - int(x))*10)))
```

Or you can cast the number to a string and [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at the decimal point.

```
print(str(x).split('.')[1][0])
```

**NOTE**: This approach will not work with large numbers as `str` will convert the float to scientific notation. This can be avoided by never converting to float

```
x = input()
print(x.split('.')[1][0])
```

Comment: Your first method will fail for negative numbers: it prints `-1` for `x = -3.14`.

Comment: ... and the second won't work for large numbers either because of rounding.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille good point. Edited to reflect that

Comment: For large numbers, as they are entered as string via `input`, the only safe way is to manipulate the string without converting it to float.

Answer (score 2):

Or just a simple function:

```py
def decimalPoint(num):
    return int((abs(num) * 10) % 10)
```

Comment: `decimalPoint(-3.14)` returns 8...

Answer (score 1):

read input and convert it to string

```
x = input()
```

find the decimal point in string and index its next element. COnvert back to integer

```
int(x[str(x).find('.')+1])
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, so converting it to float and back to string is useless, and causes problems. If I enter `12345678901234567890.1`, your code prints 2....

Comment: I edited the post and now it prints `1`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option is reading it as float first 
Example

```py
number = float(input())

first_number = number - int(number)
first_number = int(first_number * 10)
```

So the above takes in a number as float say 1.23
It then takes 1.23 and minuses the integral value of 1.23 
 I.e. 1.23. - 1 = 0.23 
After that we multiply the resulting value by 10 to get 2.3 then get the integral value of 2.3 gives us 2 which is the number you are looking for

Comment: Or ddaedalus method...

Comment: If I enter `12345678901234567890.1`, your code gives `0`....

Comment: That's because 12345678901234567890 is greater is nolonger an integer. Integers are generally values from 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 if signed or 0 to 4,294,967,295 if unsigned. This assumes that integers are stored in 4 bytes

Comment: ```int(x[str(x).find('.')+1])```  this is a good approach but what happens when you enter a number like 123.455.789?

Comment: Integers in Python have unlimited precision, and are stored in as many bytes as necessary. Floats, though, have limited precision, and converting a large number to float causes rounding, like here. As the numbered is entered as a string via `input`, converting it to float and then trying to extract a digit is bound to fail with large numbers. The safe way here is to manipulate the string without conversion.

Comment: 123.455.789 is not a valid number.